# script running python --version command is printing it too early

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, python, printing

I have a error handler script that shows my important environment variables when I fail *(I added a few <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the echo string for easier reading, the full line is added at the end of the question)*:

```
echo -e "--- failed at line $1 in function $2\nvirtual env = 
$(echo ${VIRTUAL_ENV})\ncurrent dir = ${PWD}\nbranch = $(git status | head
 -1)\ngit commit = $(git log -1 | tr '\n''\t')\npip version = $(pip -
V)\nPy version = $(python --version)\nhostname = $(logname)@$(hostname)\n"
```

I get a good result, except for the python --version part:

```
Python 2.7.12  <--- why is this here?
--- failed at line 186 in function my_func
virtual env = 
current dir = /home/bla/blabla/foo
branch = On branch goo
git commit = commit ### Author: ... 
pip version = pip 18.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-18.1-py2.7.egg/pip (python 2.7)
Py version =  <----- instead of here
hostname = X@Y
```

The actual function of mine doesn't use echo right away. I also call `tput setaf` && `tput sgr0` to modify the colors. The python line (the 1st) is not colored, while the others are...

---

```
"--- failed at line $1 in function $2\nvirtual env = $(echo ${VIRTUAL_ENV})\ncurrent dir = ${PWD}\nbranch = $(git status | head -1)\ngit commit = $(git log -1 | tr '\n''\t')\npip version = $(pip -V)\nPy version = $(python --version)\nhostname = $(logname)@$(hostname)\n"
```

Comment: Probably because `python --version` writes to stderr, not stdout

Comment: cool, didn't think of it. Does it make sense for this version command to write to stderr?

Comment: No it's not, it was a bug ([see here](https://bugs.python.org/issue18338)) and has been fixed in Python >3.4. [Also read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028416/why-does-python-print-version-info-to-stderr).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @steeldriver (nice band btw) for his comment. The fix was easier once I verified it was indeed printing to stderr - just redirect stderr to stdout for the command. i.e. `Py version = $(python --version 2>&1)`

Also thanks to @pLumo for this comment, that this error (printing to stderr instead stdout) was fixed in python 3.4 and newer

Comment: `python3 --version` works as expected.

Comment: I actually was running my script the last month on python3 env, and didn't see it, but it didn't occur to me the pyhton version was related